# Rotating a model of a character distorted the animation

Tags: animation, export, unity

I created a 3D model in Blender, I did a walk cycle on it so this character has an walking animation in it.

I want to use this model and its walk animation in Unity. But **Unity is using `Y` as *up* direction and Blender uses `Z`**, so when I exported it as FBX file into Unity, it is not working properly.

I would like to rotate the model in Blender first then export it as .fbx file. But the problem comes that when I rotated my model and applied the rotation by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, the model is rotated well but the **animation is destroyed** by the rotation, the animation is severely distorted, the legs and arms are in strange behaviors.

Comment: There are already a few questions regarding Unity and animation asked here, just search for `unity`. Not sure if it helps though, the answers are rather discouraging.